# jquery table sorter plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I need jquery grid with pagination,search and inline edit option.

I used tablesorter but after page 2, inline (jquery plugin) edit problem occurs.

I have tried flexigrid.

thanks
v.srinath

Answer (score 1):

I've just used [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) with some joy.

I should also add this very useful [detailed explanation](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/DataTables) of the usage of datatables.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://php-team.blogspot.com/2009/05/10-jquery-datagrid-plugins.html) for a list of plug-ins. May be you could try [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).